# Ngbdropdown click event not working on ios phonegap with angular 8 running cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, dropdown, angular8, ng-bootstrap

All my NgbDropdown has stopped working on ios devices (cordova app) after upgrade to Angular 8, NGBootstrap 5.

The ngbdropdown works perfect on all browsers on Windows, Apple and Android Cordova, but when used in a Cordova App on a ios device the click event is not triggered. No error is triggered in xcode.

Here is a simple example that should trigger testclick function when you click on a item:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
         <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="testclick(1)">Action - 1</button>
         <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="testclick(2)">Another Action</button>
          <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="testclick(3)">Something else is here</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the event is not triggered, but the ngbdropdown closes. Tried using focus event with no luck.

The testclick() function is never triggered, but the ngbdropdown closes normally.

If the button is placed outside the ngbdropdown everything works as expected even with the ngbDropDownItem tag:

```
<div class="col col-12 col-sm-4">
   <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="testclick(1)">Action - 1</button>            
</div>
```

Versions used:

- Angular CLI 8.3.18
- Bootstrap: 4.3.1
- NgBootstrap: 5.1.2

Have tried to downgrade Angular, but ran into a big dependency mess with my large project.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Switched to Ngx-bootstrap dropdown. It works.